# Does Apple Watch support VoIP?

Tags: twilio, voip, watchos

I'm trying to build an independent watchOS (version 8.3) app, and I tried using the Twilio voice SDK to make VoIP calls.

Obviously, the iOS SDK of Twilio does not support watchOS, now I'm wondering if watchOS 8 does even support VoIP technology?

I really couldn’t find much information about this subject, so any info/suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is being added in WatchOS 9.
https://www.macrumors.com/2022/06/07/apple-watch-voip-calling-watchos-9/

Comment: Yesss, finally! Thanks though.